# How to create zebra stripes on html table without using javascript and even/odd classes generation?

Tags: css, html-table

I want to zebra-stripe a html table without using any js stuff or writing server-side code to generate even/odd classes for table rows. Is it ever possible to do using raw css?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

It is possible, with CSS3 selectors:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}


tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: white;
}
```

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3), every browser supports it now.

Comment: by modern you mean everything but IE7 and 8

Comment: You'd probably want to scope it as `tbody tr:nth-child(even)` so it only applies to rows in the table body and not the `<thead>` or `<tfoot>` which are usually styled differently.

Answer (score 3):

If all you're changing is the background colour, then the following would work, where test.gif is a 40px high image with the top 20px one colour, and the bottom 20 pixels the other colour. If you need to change any other css properties you're pretty much stuck.

```
table {  background: url(test.gif) top; }
table tr { height: 20px; }
```

Comment: That is a singularly inflexible approach.

Comment: @Mike Adler - absolutely, but for browsers that don't support :nth-child, and without js/server side changes there's not much you can do.

Comment: Clever.  Though, this will annoy users who need to read larger text sizes than will fit in the `20px` cell height.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd
CSS 3 nth-child. Since browser support is limited you can reproduce the behavior with Sizzle (included in, jquery for example)

Answer (score 0):

(In CSS <= 2) Nope. Unfortunately there aren't any selectors (in CSS <= 2) that operate based on the position (in terms of the number it is within it's parent's children) which I believe you would need to do this with just CSS.

Note to self: read up on CSS3, already!

Answer (score 0):

In http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos you can find explanation and examples on using nth-child:

```
tr:nth-child(2n+1) /* represents every odd row of an HTML table */ {
  background-color: green;
}
tr:nth-child(odd)  /* same */ {
  background-color: green;
}
tr:nth-child(2n+0) /* represents every even row of an HTML table */ {
  background-color: pink;
}
tr:nth-child(even) /* same */ {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Good luck with [browser compatibility](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild) - you'll need it.
There are hacks to make it work in IE (using JS) - I'll leave that sifting to you.

Comment: You don't even need the `+0` on `2n+0`