# W3C Validator tells me I have an Error, not sure how to fix

Tags: html, css

So I am writing a css page for my class, and I noticed that the style which I applied to span is not applying at all, so I went to http://validator.w3.org/ to check what I did wrong and it gave me this error message

```
"Line 32, Column 6: Start tag span seen in table."
```

This is my line 32

```
<span><tr><td>Mars needs moms</td><td>$150,000,000</td><td>$38,992,758</td><td>$130,503,621</td><td>2011</td></tr></span>
```

Here is the code for that particular style

```
span{background-color=:#666;font-weight:bold;color:white;}
```

Basically my goal is to make this table haveevery other row in the table with a background color being black with the text being white

This is the full code, incase the error made which isn't applying this style is somewhere else. *there  are other styles in there which don't apply to anything yet, as this is not finished yet*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Lowest Grossing Movies of all time</title>
<style>
span{background-color=:#666;font-weight:bold;color:white;}
p{text-decoration:underline;line-height:200%;}
h1{text-align:center;font-size:125%;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
th,td{padding:25px;}
</style>                
</head>
<body>
<h1> Lowest Grossing Movies of All Time </h1>
<table border="1">
<tr><th>Title</th><th>Production Budget</th><th>World Wide Gross</th><th>Net Loss</th>    <th>Release Year</th></tr>
<span><tr><td>Mars needs moms</td><td>$150,000,000</td><td>$38,992,758</td>    <td>$130,503,621</td><td>2011</td></tr></span>
<tr><td>The 13th Warrior</td><td>$160,000,000</td><td>$61,698,899</td><td>$129,150,551</td><td>1999</td></tr>
<span><tr><td>The Lone Ranger</td><td>$225,000,000</td><td>$243,377,083</td><td>$103,311,459</td><td>2013</td></tr></span>
<tr><td>R.I.P.D.</td><td>$130,000,000</td><td>$66,627,120</td><td>$96,6865,440</td><td>2013</tr>
<span><tr><td>John Carter</td><td>$250,00,00</td><td>$282,778,100</td><td>$108,610,950</td><td>2012</td></tr></span>
</table> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have the `<span>` inside each `<td>`, you cannot have it at the `<tr>` level, or to make it easier just change the style and do something like `table tr td {background-color=:#666;font-weight:bold;color:white;}`

Comment: The *only* valid child elements of a `table` element are `thead`, `tfoot`, `tbody` and `tr`. That's all. A `span` should ***not*** appear in a `table` *unless* it's wrapped inside of a `th` or `td`.

Comment: It's not part of the question, but PLEASE not that `W3C != W3Schools`

Comment: `.numberOfTheBeast {background-color=:#666;font-weight:bold;color:white;}` and `<tr class="numberOfTheBeast" ...`

Comment: Oh, okay so I just need to move the span tag inside the td and tr elements every other row and it should work right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create zebra stripes on html table without using javascript and even/odd classes generation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765510/how-to-create-zebra-stripes-on-html-table-without-using-javascript-and-even-odd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest problem you're facing is that there are limited elements that are valid children of the HTML `table` element, these are:

- `colgroup`,
- `caption`,
- `thead`,
- `tfoot`,
- `tbody`, and
- `tr`

So removing the `span` elements from the `table` solves that problem. Also, you'd forgotten to close one of the `td` elements (you closed the `tr`, but forgot the `td`); this is why readable HTML is easier to maintain (it's simply easier to see the code, and omissions, when it's indented and white-spaced).

Incidentally, using your original HTML, had you used your browser's developer tools (such as Web Inspector under Chromium, or Firebug under Mozilla), you'd have been able to inspect the DOM, which would've shown you the brower's (unpredictable and unreliable) reordering of the HTML in order to produce a valid document). For example, Web Inspector shows:

[image]

[JS Fiddle 'source' for above image](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2MLdD/1/).

Note the three `span` elements moved before the `table` element, from the `table` itself.

Your corrected HTML:

```
<h1> Lowest Grossing Movies of All Time </h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Production Budget</th>
        <th>World Wide Gross</th>
        <th>Net Loss</th>
        <th>Release Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mars needs moms</td>
        <td>$150,000,000</td>
        <td>$38,992,758</td>
        <td>$130,503,621</td>
        <td>2011</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The 13th Warrior</td>
        <td>$160,000,000</td>
        <td>$61,698,899</td>
        <td>$129,150,551</td>
        <td>1999</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The Lone Ranger</td>
        <td>$225,000,000</td>
        <td>$243,377,083</td>
        <td>$103,311,459</td>
        <td>2013</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>R.I.P.D.</td>
        <td>$130,000,000</td>
        <td>$66,627,120</td>
        <td>$96,6865,440</td>
        <td>2013</td> <!-- you omitted a closing </td> tag here -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John Carter</td>
        <td>$250,00,00</td>
        <td>$282,778,100</td>
        <td>$108,610,950</td>
        <td>2012</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Using CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

/* using ':nth-child(odd)' to style the 'td' elements
   of the alternate/odd rows of the table */
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: #ffa;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2MLdD/).

References:

- [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).
- [`:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).

Comment: Alright, I didn't even know that was a possible tag, thank you so much for this information. Although I must ask, did you just correct the format by hand? What you typed looks very neat compared to the mess I typed up, is it just your experience with this, or is there a way to take jumbled un-organized code and make it neatly formatted?

Comment: You're very welcome indeed! As for tidying? My advice (for tidying up *existing* HTML, CSS or JavaScript) is to paste into [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) (using the appropriate panel for the code you want to tidy) and click the 'TidyUp' button. There is, obviously, an element of familiarity and experience, but it's easier to use a tool for tidying, rather than by hand. When *writing*, however, I find it easier to keep it tidy as I go (and then use JS Fiddle to tidy the end-result, just to ensure matched indentation).

Answer (score 1):

In most modern browsers this could be achieved with css:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#666;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
}
```

No span tags required. (Remove them)

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/uB2GR/

Answer (score 0):

You've placed `<span>` elements between two `<tr>` elements. This is not valid HTML. You need to place your entire `<span>` inside a table cell.

```
<tr><td><span>Some stuff</span></td><td><span>More stuff</span></td></tr>
```

if you're doing this for styling purposes there's probably a better way with classes applied to the `<td>` elements