# CSS(SCSS?) selector used to create zebra background for table

Tags: html, css

I am new to coding and I have been having some trouble creating a zebra background for a table...where no matter how I select the elements with CSS, nothing would show up.

the target code looks something like this:

```
<table class="striped">
  <tr>
    <td class="main">
      Test Submit
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

where the  block (from  to ) repeats a few more times, thus creating a table.

And below is the CSS code I attempted to create the zebra background:

```
table.striped {
  tbody tr:nth-child(even){ background: red;}
}
```

I have searched online for answers and many seem to be sharing the same code as I have written (or something similar)...but mine has nothing showing up.

Did I mistaken how the selectors work in css? That the selector (tbody tr:nth-child(even)) does not target all the even numbered  as I had hoped?

And is there a good-way to debug css related question? 
console.log doesn't return a very meaningful message most of the time.

Your assistance is much appreciated!

PS. I have found some answers that did the trick in jQuery...but I am sure CSS can do it as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765510/how-to-create-zebra-stripes-on-html-table-without-using-javascript-and-even-odd duplicate

Comment: thanks for the reply! but ya that's one of the answers I found...;_; (I'll try again but I believe I've used its answer before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add more rows to the table. Because even is each second row.

Also your css is invalid

```
table.striped tr:nth-child(even) { background: red;}
```

http://jsbin.com/wigitequxu/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 3):

First thing I see is that your HTML snippet doesn't seem to be complete: the closing `</table>` is missing.

Then, you will need more rows to your table to be able to see the custom style on even ones.

And last, you are nesting CSS declarations, thus making them invalid.

Here's a [working example based on your code](http://jsfiddle.net/ojhg6jnb/).

--
Edit: Sorry, didn't see the answer was already posted before I posted mine.

Comment: No need to apologise if you post another answer, you also included some additional information too, and it doesn't matter either way :)

Comment: thanks for the reply! Yes I have more <tr></tr> blocks in my code but I felt posting the entire thing would be redundant. I'll try and fix my code base on your example. Thanks again!