# JavaScript Validation Else If not working - alert for If is, else is not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

So I'm making a dynamic table which takes inputs for values of a Miles to Kilometers table.  My HTML works fine, and my functions for the displaying of the table works fine, however when adding validation to this to make sure that negative Integers cannot be inputted, the if statement in my for loop works, but the else statements break the code.  I am extremely confused as to why.

Here is my JS code:

```
  for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement("tr");
    if (i <= -1)
      alert("Value must be positive Integer");
    else if (i % 2 == 0)
      tr.setAttribute("class", "even");
    else
      tr.setAttribute("class", "odd");
```

It is the if else which does not work.  I'd be grateful for some help!

Comment: Is it possible to create a snippet, or fiddle that "demonstrates" the issue so that we can have a better look. I meant, adding the necessary HTML will make it easy.

Comment: What's with the loop, why not just `if ( from < 0 ) ...`

Comment: what is the error output ?

Comment: if(i <= -1)
    alert("Value must be positive Integer");
         else if(i%2==0)
    tr.setAttribute("class", "even");
   else
    tr.setAttribute("class", "odd");
        bod.appendChild(tr);

Comment: FYI CSS can zebra stripe a table [all on its own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765510/how-to-create-zebra-stripes-on-html-table-without-using-javascript-and-even-odd) so I would remove that logic completely

Comment: You can put if (i <= -1) out of loop it self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
if (i <= -1){
  alert("Value must be positive Integer");
  return false;
}
else if (i % 2 == 0)
  tr.setAttribute("class", "even");
else
  tr.setAttribute("class", "odd");
```

Using [break;](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp)

```
if (i <= -1)
  alert("Value must be positive Integer");
  break;
else if (i % 2 == 0)
  tr.setAttribute("class", "even");
else
  tr.setAttribute("class", "odd");
```

Comment: You may use `break` instead to make sure the code after the initial `for` will run.

Comment: @Dionys Great observation... Thank you.. I have updated the code

Comment: Thank you!! This fixed my issue! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (from > -1 && to>=from) {
for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement("tr");
    if (i % 2 == 0)
      tr.setAttribute("class", "even");
    else
      tr.setAttribute("class", "odd");
}
else{
alert("Value must be positive Integer");
}
```